# seekbar thumb center not at the start point

Tags: android, seekbar

[image]

as my pic,the seekbar progress =0,but the seekbar thumb center not at the start point.my code:

```
   <SeekBar  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
                 android:thumb="@drawable/seekbarthumb"
                 android:minHeight="10dip"
                 android:maxHeight="10dip"
                 android:thumbOffset="0px"
                 android:max="100"
                 android:id="@+id/bright_seekbar"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"/>
```

seekbar_progress

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:id="@android:id/background"> 
    <shape> 
        <corners android:radius="5dip" /> 
        <gradient 
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d" 
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a" 
                android:centerY="0.75" 
                android:endColor="#ff747674" 
                android:angle="270" 
        /> 
    </shape> 
</item> 
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"> 
    <clip> 
        <shape> 
            <corners android:radius="5dip" /> 
            <gradient 
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300" 
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600" 
                    android:centerY="0.75" 
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00" 
                    android:angle="270" 
            /> 
        </shape> 
    </clip> 
</item> 
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"> 
    <clip> 
        <shape> 
            <corners android:radius="5dip" /> 
            <gradient 
                    android:startColor="#FFD700" 
                    android:centerColor="#FFB90F" 
                    android:centerY="0.75" 
                    android:endColor="#FFA500" 
                    android:angle="270" 
            /> 
        </shape> 
    </clip> 
 </item> 


</layer-list>
```

seekbarthumb.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_button__volume" />
<item android:state_focused="true" 
      android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_button__volume" />
<item
     android:drawable="@drawable/default_button__volume" />     
</selector>
```

default_button__volume is image

Comment: @drawable/seekbarthumb is an image or xml?

Comment: seekbarthumb is a image,but i use the system seekbarthumb not the useful.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113545/android-cant-put-thumb-on-center-of-a-seek-bar

Answer (score 9):

finally found the answer, the case here is that `android:thumbOffset` is **NOT** a setter for the thumb place along with the **progress bar**, but, it's the *thumb length* **from** it's beginning **to** it's center point so that the `seekbar` can adjust the thumb's center point at it's beginning point. So, if we have a thumb image with a **width** of `50`, the `thumbOffset` has to be `25` (50/2), so that the `seekbar` will adjust the **zero value** at the **pixel 25** of the thumb which will make the thumb appears to be exactly at the middle.
thanks for [that man](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21996607/1638739) who redirect me to know that.

Answer (score 3):

Your thumb image needs to have it's yellow dot at the center (horizontally); add transparent pixels left or right to make it so. Then, change `android:thumbOffset` to be exactly half your thumb image size. For example, if your image is **10dp** in width, set `android:thumbOffset` to **5dp**.

Comment: But how to set 10dp for thumb image (NOT drawable)?

Answer (score 1):

For me solution is to add `android:thumbOffset` value as suitable for your layout rather than setting it as half of your thumb icon width. If you set `android:thumbOffset` as +ve value (e.g 10dp) your thumb moves towards **left side** and this value is -ve (e.g -10dp) than your thumb moves towards **right side**.

Answer (score 0):

try giving the thumbOffset in the seekbar a negative value (like -3px).

Comment: it is no useful,i have tested it

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
android:progress="0"
```

for `seekbar` in xml file.

**OR**

in `Java` activity file:

```
SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.bright_seekbar);
sb.setMax(100);
sb.setProgress(0); // Set it to zero so it will start at the left-most edge
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: not useful ,i have add it to test. the seekbar start point is the thumb the left point,so it is not useful,if i delete the thumb image transparency shadow,it is ok. but system seekbar thumb center is the the seekbar start point.if i used the system  thumb, it is the now result.

Answer (score 0):

Set thumbOffset of your seekbar equal to double of thumb width. If width of your thumb is 8dp, then set android:thumbOffset equal to 16dp.
It worked in my case.